# How to show the firewall log on a mac (Mountain Lion)?

Tags: macos, firewall, osx-mountain-lion

Where do I find firewall log on mountain lion 10.8.2?

I have a problem with refused connections and I want to see if the firewall prevents me from connecting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file is located in `/var/log/appfirewall.log` and you can access that by using your favorite command-line text editor or alternatively you can use the Apple Console application. On the left pane of the Console app, you see "/var/log" and a bunch of files - appfirewall.log is one of the first ones.

[image]

Comment: to see what's going on I use `tail -f /var/log/appfirewall.log`